# Java Calendar: Subtract two Dates to get difference in days between the two

Tags: java

I want to check how many days it has been since my user logged in:

```
Calendar lastLogin = Calendar.getInstance();
lastLogin.setTime(randomPlayer.getLastLogin());
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
```

How would I subtract this to get the difference in days between the two? I.e number of days since last login.

Comment: what is the vesion of java that you use?

Comment: version 8+ , usually latest

Comment: It is highly recommended *not* to use the `Calendar` and `Date` classes anymore. If you're using Java 8, use `java.time`. If you're using an earlier version, use Joda-Time. `Calendar` and `Date` are really crufty, inefficient classes.

Comment: You can use java time   Period period= Period.between(date1, date2); then use  period.getDays() to get day

Comment: that can be helpful for you http://www.javabrahman.com/quick-tips/java-8-how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-java-time-localdate-instances/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) instead:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class DaysBetween {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate lastLogin = LocalDate.of(2017, 4, 1);
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println(daysBetween(lastLogin, today));
    }

    private static long daysBetween(LocalDate from, LocalDate to) {
        return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from, to);
    }
}
```

Or, if you *really* want to stick to `Calendar`:

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DaysBetween {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar lastLogin = Calendar.getInstance();
        lastLogin.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
        lastLogin.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
        lastLogin.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(daysBetween(lastLogin, today));
    }

    private static long daysBetween(Calendar from, Calendar to) {
        return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from.toInstant(), to.toInstant());
    }
}
```